# How to set up psgraph to get the same output produced by pspicture plus psaxes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

In order to get a more balanced diagram (of a certain specified metric size, `width` times `height`), I usually also specify some offsets or adjustment values around the canvas (aka picture) and axes as follows. Note the annotations are added only to ease our discussion.

[image]

`POT` and `AOT`, for example, stand for **P** icture **O** ffset (aka canvas offset) and **A** xes **O** ffset, respectively. Canvas size and all offsets are usually in centimeter.

The following is my MWE. The annotation related codes have been removed for the sake of simplicity.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

% User defined data:
\def\f(#1){2.5*cos(2*#1)}% function to plot

\const{Width}{8}% total width in cm
\const{Height}{7}% total height in cm 

\const{POL}{-1.00}% pspicture left offset in cm
\const{POR}{ 0.75}% pspicture right offset in cm
\const{POB}{-1.00}% pspicture bottom offset in cm
\const{POT}{ 0.75}% pspicture top offset in cm

\const{AOL}{-0.50}% axis left offset in cm
\const{AOR}{ 0.75}% axis right offset in cm
\const{AOB}{-0.50}% axis bottom offset in cm
\const{AOT}{ 0.75}% axis top offset in cm

\const{DomL}{-2*pi}% domain left 
\const{DomR}{pi}% domain right 
\const{DomB}{-3}% domain bottom 
\const{DomT}{ 3}% domain top

\const[0]{TrigLabelBase}{2}% denominator for a fraction of pi

% Internal used constants:
\const{XUnit}{(Width-POR+POL-AOR+AOL)/(DomR-DomL)}
\const{YUnit}{(Height-POT+POB-AOT+AOB)/(DomT-DomB)}

\const{PicL}{(POL+AOL)/XUnit+DomL}
\const{PicR}{(POR+AOR)/XUnit+DomR}
\const{PicB}{(POB+AOB)/YUnit+DomB}
\const{PicT}{(POT+AOT)/YUnit+DomT}

\const{AxiL}{AOL/XUnit+DomL}
\const{AxiR}{AOR/XUnit+DomR}
\const{AxiB}{AOB/YUnit+DomB}
\const{AxiT}{AOT/YUnit+DomT}

\const{DeltaX}{pi/TrigLabelBase}

\psset{xunit=\XUnit,yunit=\YUnit,algebraic,plotpoints=500}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\PicL,\PicB)(\PicR,\PicT)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{\DomL}{\DomR}{\f(x)}
    \psaxes
    [
        trigLabels=true,
        linecolor=gray,
        labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-1.5pt 1.5pt,
        xlabelsep=3pt,
        arrowscale=1,
        trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
        dx=\DeltaX,% must come before xunit to avoid getting a strange output!  
    ]{->}(0,0)(\AxiL,\AxiB)(\AxiR,\AxiT)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I know that `psgraph` can do scaling automatically based on the specified metric size (in centimeter, e.g.) of canvas on which graphs and axes are drawn.

The problem is how to setup the `psgraph` to get the same result as what I already got above with `pspicture` and `psaxes`? `psgraph` seems to be a promising syntactical sugar that can reduce more keystrokes!

Comment: To be more exciting, I will present a bounty of 500 for the first satisfied answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

% User defined data:
\def\f(#1){2.5*cos(2*#1)}% function to plot

\const{Width}{8}% total width in cm
\const{Height}{7}% total height in cm 

\const{POL}{-1.00}% pspicture left offset in cm
\const{POR}{ 0.75}% pspicture right offset in cm
\const{POB}{-1.00}% pspicture bottom offset in cm
\const{POT}{ 0.75}% pspicture top offset in cm

\const{AOL}{-0.50}% axis left offset in cm
\const{AOR}{ 0.75}% axis right offset in cm
\const{AOB}{-0.50}% axis bottom offset in cm
\const{AOT}{ 0.75}% axis top offset in cm

\const{DomL}{-2*pi}% domain left 
\const{DomR}{pi}% domain right 
\const{DomB}{-3}% domain bottom 
\const{DomT}{ 3}% domain top

\const[0]{TrigLabelBase}{2}% denominator for a fraction of pi

% Internal used constants:
\const{XUnit}{(Width-POR+POL-AOR+AOL)/(DomR-DomL)}
\const{YUnit}{(Height-POT+POB-AOT+AOB)/(DomT-DomB)}

\const{PicL}{(POL+AOL)/XUnit+DomL}
\const{PicR}{(POR+AOR)/XUnit+DomR}
\const{PicB}{(POB+AOB)/YUnit+DomB}
\const{PicT}{(POT+AOT)/YUnit+DomT}

\const{AxiL}{AOL/XUnit+DomL}
\const{AxiR}{AOR/XUnit+DomR}
\const{AxiB}{AOB/YUnit+DomB}
\const{AxiT}{AOT/YUnit+DomT}

\const{DeltaX}{pi/TrigLabelBase}

\psset{xunit=\XUnit,yunit=\YUnit,algebraic,plotpoints=500}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\PicL,\PicB)(\PicR,\PicT)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{\DomL}{\DomR}{\f(x)}
    \psaxes
    [
        trigLabels=true,
        linecolor=gray,
        labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-1.5pt 1.5pt,
        xlabelsep=3pt,
        arrowscale=1,
        trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
        dx=\DeltaX,% must come before xunit to avoid getting a strange output!  
    ]{->}(0,0)(\AxiL,\AxiB)(\AxiR,\AxiT)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}

\psset{unit=1cm}
\psset{llx=\POL cm,urx=\POR cm,lly=\POB cm,ury=\POT cm}

\begin{psgraph}[
        trigLabels=true,
        linecolor=gray,
        labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-1.5pt 1.5pt,
        xlabelsep=3pt,
        arrowscale=1,
        trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
        dx=\DeltaX]{->}(0,0)(\AxiL,\AxiB)(\AxiR,\AxiT)
         {\dimexpr \Width cm +\POL cm - \POR cm}
         {\dimexpr\Height cm +\POB cm - \POT cm}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{\DomL}{\DomR}{\f(x)}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but oh my ghost. You  also made it depend on my defined `\POR`, etc. :-) I thought it can be simplified much.

Comment: sure! nobody needs your definitions. `psgraph` can be used without all that.

Comment: So how dod you make use of `\psgraph` without using my defined `\Axi*`?

Comment: use simple values and set the border with `llx,lly,...` that's all ...